# How to find user location using php

Tags: php

We need to find current location of user

user can find shop near where the user is at that moment, distance is in kilometers, meters

We have tried following tool/libraries

1) ipinfodb
http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

2) HTML5 Geolocoation API

any API is not proving me actual latitude and longitude.

Comment: I don't think it is possible via PHP. You need GPS system to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure why you seem to think the HTML5 geolocation API doesn't give a lat/long for the user. Assuming the user allows your page to know their location, you should have location data.

http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html is a very good quick look into the HTML5 gelolocation API. It even has a small example further down the page.